# I can't run my code

Tags: jquery

Hi, I have this code and I can't get it to work. I'm new with Ajax jQuery and JavaScript so please be nice :) and thank you for the help :)
This code should be a simple form validation but when I tab in to the next input box it does nothing. It should be displaying an error message that the uname is less than 5 characters long. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateUsername(){
    var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    if(uname<5){
        document.getElementById("errormsg").value = "wait";
    }

}
</script>

<body>
<form method=post id=regform action=jscript.html>
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type=text name=uname id=uname onBlur="javascript:validateUsername()"/></td>
        <td><input type=hidden name=errormsg value='' id=errormsg"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type=text name=uname id=uname onBlur="javascript:validatePassword()"/></td>
        <td><input type=hidden name=errormsg value='' id=errormsg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: The "javascript:" is unnecessary in the onblur event. It's implied that the content within quotes is JavaScript. You should also have quotes around attribute values, like `name="uname"`.

Comment: What browser are you using? Most modern browsers have a 'javascript console' which is an invaluable debugging tool. Using one might help you find your problem here.

Comment: Your problem right now isn't so much that you're new to programming and is instead that you've given us very little information from which we can help you. Please edit your question with: (1) What errors you're getting. (2) Expected behavior. (3) Actual behavior. Good luck!

Comment: im sorry still new here so i dont know what to do well actually it doesnt do anything when i press tab. it goes to the other input box and does nothing i want the errormsg thing to comeout if the inputed username is less than 5 but it is not working :(

Comment: @user1376251 Ok, so on the top, right hand side you should see a wrench icon. If you go `wrench > tools > Javascript console` it will bring up the Javascript Console at the bottom of your window. If you click on the 'console' tab you will see any errors or warning messages associated with the javascript on the current page. Are there any messages in there?

Comment: @jmort how do i get it to work i have some code here that works but its my friend's code and i dont understand it well.. im trying to study how this thing works so i made a test html like this :(

Comment: ok. I would start by making sure you have Google Chrome. Right click, then click Inspect. Learn how to use the console to spot errors. Also, you may want to try something much simpler if you're just getting started. You don't often see form actions linking to HTML files, so I suspect you'll run into problems in a lot of different areas. Consider breaking the code down and focusing on smaller pieces that you can work with. Good luck! :)

Comment: @david i dont have any errors.. i think there is something lacking in my code that i dont know..

Comment: @user1376251 No worries. I suggest you keep this tool in mind, It WILL (that's a guarantee) help you as do more web programming. For now some answers to your question have spotted some of your problems.

Comment: @jmort yah i use chrome the form action is the main html itself i mean the script is within that jscript.html. oh i am really having a hard time understanding this codes i need to learn them in 2 days :(

Comment: one more suggestion: use `console.info("This is a log statement")` in your code so you can trace the code. Also, you **STILL** haven't edited your question (using the "edit" link below it) to describe what you expect the code to do vs what it's actually doing. Until you do that you're going to continue to see an endless stream of guesses posted as answers below.

Comment: oh sorry lol and thank you for all your help ill edit this thing first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, i hope it will help.
You need to improve your html, put quotes around value of every attribute like  **type="text" name="uname"** and all you was writing is javascript, not jquery, so you also not need to include that .js file.
in your function validateUsername, uname holds the number of characters entered by user, and if its less then 5, then errormsg (which is id of a div) will show **wait** msg

you don't need input type="hidden" to show error message to user, use DIV or SPAN for that

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateUsername(){
    var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value.length;
if(uname<5){
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "wait";
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="regform" action="jscript.html">
<table>
<tr>    
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" onBlur="validateUsername()"/></td>
    <td><div id="errormsg"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Giving the asker working code without explaining what changes you've made will not help them at all. They'll have the same problems next time.

Comment: @pal - Edit your answer to include an explanation. David can then decide if he wants to remove the downvote after you've corrected the problem he indicated in your answer. Good luck! :)

Comment: Also, this still has some errors... like the uname<5 needing to be uname.length<5. Consider trying the code in a jsfiddle so you can verify it works.

Comment: @jmort253 he wrote `var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value.length;`, it's supposed to work. Edit: there's a duplicate ID but he can easily fix that.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Oops. Thanks for pointing that out. But that goes back to David's original point as to why it's important to describe the changes :) People miss them.

Comment: i had added some explanation, i hope i won't see the downvote

Comment: @palsingh I have removed downvote now that you have some more explanation. But as jmort253 says please also *check* you answer. You still have 2 elements with the same id so this is still an invalid document!

Answer (score 1):

(uname<5) must be (uname.length<5) I guess

Answer (score 1):

Some of your problems are:

```
 <input type=hidden name=errormsg value='' id=errormsg"/>
```

You are missing a set of inverted commas around the `id` value. It should read:

```
 <input type=hidden name=errormsg value='' id="errormsg"/>
```

Also, in HTML ids need to be *unique* throughout the document. So you aren't allowed to have 2 input fields with the id "errormsg" you have to give them different ones.

Also, as Wezelkrozum has spotted you need to measure the *length* of the username.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from testing your code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code.

Here's a live example of how you may go about your problem.

http://jsbin.com/oyejic/7/edit#javascript,html,live

I would encourage you to play with the example in jsbin. 
Below is the code from the jsbin example (with external links to libraries removed).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="jquery.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="regform" action="jscript.html">
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="uname_errormsg" value="" id="uname_errormsg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pword" id="pword" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="pword_errormsg" value="" id="pword_errormsg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

  <div id="testing"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateField( inputID ) {
    var fieldName = $('#' + inputID).val();
    if ( fieldName.length < 5 ) {
        $('#' + inputID + '_errormsg').val("wait");
        $("#testing").empty()
                     .text("hey, wait " + inputID + "!" ); 
    } else {
        $("#testing").empty()
                     .text("Ah, 5 or more characters for " + inputID + "!" );     
    }
} 

  $("#uname, #pword").blur(function() {
    validateField( this.id ); 
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A couple of notes:

1. You may benefit by beginning to learn the [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) library.
   You reference jQuery in your code, but you're not making any use of it. 
   The example I've posted does make use of jQuery.
2. Try to avoid inline javascript. Putting javascript events such as `onBlur="javascript:validateUsername()"` 
   right inside your html can be messy and lead to maintenance issue.
3. Close your html attributes. `id=errormsg"` should be `id="errormsg"`
4. You may also find it worthwhile to give [Javascript Enlightenment](http://javascriptenlightenment.com/) a 
   read.